# How to Log Out of Ask Different

Tags: discussion

I have recently joined Ask Different and can log in but how do I log out when I want to leave the page? I can't find a 'log out' or 'sign out' button.

Comment: Last icon on the right side of the menu bar.

Answer (score 3):

I usually don't log out so that I can just click a link and I'm in, but the log out option is in the StackExchange icon in the upper right corner of the screen:

1. Click that Icon
2. Select log out

[image: Logging Out]